Proxy contract : An error occurred during the deployment process: Error: could not decode result data
I'm trying to implement and test a proxy pattern for my smart contracts using Hardhat and Ethers.js. However, I'm encountering an issue when I attempt to call the functions of the implementation contract through the proxy. Below are the details of my setup and the error I'm receiving.
Issue During deployment, the value is set successfully through the proxy, but when I try to retrieve it, I receive the following error:   An error occurred during the deployment process: Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getValue", "signature": "getValue()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.13.2)
Storage contract
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
    contract StorageTest {
        uint256 public value; // Variabile di stato per memorizzare un valore
        address[50] private ______gap; // Spazio riservato per aggiungere variabili di stato future
    }

Proxy contract
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract ProxyTest {
    address private implementation;

    constructor(address _implementation) {
        implementation = _implementation;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        address impl = implementation;
        require(impl != address(0), "Implementation contract required");

        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40) // Carica il puntatore della memoria libera
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize()) // Copia i dati della chiamata nella memoria
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), impl, ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0) // Esegue delegatecall
            let size := returndatasize() // Ottieni la dimensione dei dati restituiti
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size) // Copia i dati restituiti nella memoria

            switch result
            case 0 {
                revert(ptr, size) // Se il risultato è 0, esegui revert
            }
            default {
                return(ptr, size) // Restituisci i dati se la chiamata è andata a buon fine
            }
        }
    }
}

Implementation contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "../storage/StorageTest.sol";
contract ImplementationTest is StorageTest {
    // Evento per tracciare quando viene impostato un nuovo valore
    event ValueSet(uint256 value);

    // Imposta il valore nella memoria
    function setValue(uint256 _value) public {
        value = _value;
        emit ValueSet(value); // Emissione dell'evento dopo aver impostato il valore
    }

    // Ottieni il valore dalla memoria
    function getValue() public view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}

deployement
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  try {
    console.log("Starting the deployment process...");

    // Ottieni il signer (account del deployer)
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

    // Ottieni il bilancio dell'account usando il provider
    const balance = await deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address);
    console.log("Account balance:", ethers.formatEther(balance), "ETH");

    // Deploy del contratto di storage
    console.log("Deploying the Storage contract...");
    const Storage = await ethers.getContractFactory("StorageTest");
    const storage = await Storage.deploy();
    await storage.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const storageAddress = await storage.getAddress(); // Ottieni l'indirizzo del contratto deployato
    console.log("Storage contract deployed to:", storageAddress);

    // Deploy del contratto di implementazione
    console.log("Deploying the Implementation contract...");
    const Implementation = await ethers.getContractFactory("ImplementationTest");
    const implementation = await Implementation.deploy();
    await implementation.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const implementationAddress = await implementation.getAddress();
    console.log("Implementation contract deployed to:", implementationAddress);

    // Deploy del contratto proxy
    console.log("Deploying the Proxy contract...");
    const Proxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("ProxyTest");
    const proxy = await Proxy.deploy(implementationAddress);
    await proxy.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const proxyAddress = await proxy.getAddress();
    console.log("Proxy contract deployed to:", proxyAddress);

    // Interagisci con il contratto tramite il proxy
    console.log("Attaching the implementation contract to the proxy...");
    const implementationWithProxy = await ethers.getContractAt("ImplementationTest", proxyAddress);

    // Imposta un valore tramite il proxy
    const newValue = 42;
    console.log(`Setting the value ${newValue} through the proxy...`);
    const tx = await implementationWithProxy.setValue(newValue);
    console.log("Transaction hash:", tx.hash);
    await tx.wait(); // Attendi che la transazione venga minata
    console.log("Value has been set.");

    // Ottieni il valore tramite il proxy
    console.log("Retrieving the value through the proxy...");
    const value = await implementationWithProxy.getValue();
    console.log("Value from proxy:", value.toString());

    console.log("Deployment process completed successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred during the deployment process:", error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
}

main();

deployment log result:
Starting the deployment process...
Deploying contracts with the account: 0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9
Account balance: 9999.99970664037957608 ETH
Deploying the Storage contract...
Storage contract deployed to: 0x66Db6d191cd163F56197b767928A507dF8b47AA7
Deploying the Implementation contract...
Implementation contract deployed to: 0xbD3afEF4b26918cDb922F9D80aeA9b8e64524432
Deploying the Proxy contract...
Proxy contract deployed to: 0x1CfD8455F189c56a4FBd81EB7D4118DB04616BA8
Attaching the implementation contract to the proxy...
Setting the value 42 through the proxy...
Transaction hash: 0x0841f97502ba2cb6d7f88c46e3aa8b7eafff9df7d8d05fe9f7f9bf8e0061c450
Value has been set.
Retrieving the value through the proxy...
An error occurred during the deployment process: Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getValue", "signature": "getValue()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.13.2)
    at makeError (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:916:15)
    at staticCallResult (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:346:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at staticCall (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:303:24)
    at Proxy.getValue (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:351:41)
    at main (C:\Users\Bruno\source\smartshopperpay\smartcontracts\scripts\deploy\deployTestProxy.js:53:19) {
  code: 'BAD_DATA',
  value: '0x',
  info: { method: 'getValue', signature: 'getValue()' },
  shortMessage: 'could not decode result data'
}


Please reduce your amount of code to just present the problematic part, to minimize the amount of code. That would radically improve the odds of someone going through your problem - currently it'd be quite time consuming for others to analyze your setup.

You have a storage clash problem.
In the proxy, the implementation address is saved at slot 0:
address private implementation;  // this is slot 0

In the implementation, the value is saved at slot 0 too:
uint256 public value;  // also slot 0

So when you change the value you also change the implementation. You should put the implementation at a different slot. Have a look at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Utils.sol
